# Process data in migration

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm normalizing a table by removing a column and breaking it out in another table. Before the column is removed I need to create new entities based on the data from this column.

This all need to be done with one single deploy and migration command. So the flow need to be like this.

1. Create new table user_roles
2. Create user_role entities with data from user->role
3. Remove column role from user table

What is the best praxis for doing this? 
Should I run some data processing code in the actual migration?

Is this kosher or should I just write a command that will do the data processing and then delete the column from this command. That feels a bit counter intuitive since this will not happen automatically if the application would be deployed fresh on a new server (since the column then is not removed in a migration)

Here's a mockup of what I want to do.

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('user_roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('organisation_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');

        $table->foreign('role_id')
            ->references('id')->on('roles')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');

        $table->foreign('organisation_id')
            ->references('id')->on('organisations')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');
    });

    // MOCKUP CODE FOR creating user_roles
    $users = User::all();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $userRole = new UserRole();
        $userRole->user_id = $user->id;
        $userRole->role_id = $user->role;
        $userRole->organisation_id = $user->getOrganisation();
        $userRole->save();
    }

    Schema::table('users', function($table) {
        $table->dropColumn('role');
    });
}
```

Comment: You should separate migrations and model updating.
You can write you own artisan command for updating needed data. 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/artisan

Comment: How many rows is that?

Comment: @AndreySvyrydov Yes I know about commands. The problem is that this command needs to be run between the migration that creates the user_roles table and the migration that removes the roles column from the users table.

Comment: @Kyslik less than 100

Comment: What are the environments; is it on production already? Do you have more than one dev working on it? Can you easily coordinate that now there is *maintenance*. The simplest way is to: write a migration that fixes everything and also truncates data, after that just run a seeder (that you generate from previous MySQL state) that fills up the table again; you may need to disable FK checks for this. You may also consider to rewrite all the migrations and make a new *git-tag* so you keep your migrations nice and simple; we do this every Laravel release.

Comment: Also note; everything is kosher if developer running the code understands it, so make sure you dent the documentation a bit on this topic.

Comment: Extend Schema class and add in child class needed functionality. And in migration run you new class.

Comment: I think the best way here add new option to migrations. Here article how you can do this https://hackernoon.com/extending-laravels-migration-command-to-add-new-options-90b5a0fc4ef4 .
In this case on production everythink will be ok.

Comment: Maybe using seeders is the better way? https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/seeding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `Users::all()` will kill the process if there are several thousand of `users`.

I would suggest not to do any `model` or data-manipulations in migrations. what will happen to you migrations if you will drop some of your models in the future?

And if your project is already working on production, then I would do this:

1. Run `migration` to create `roles` table
2. Make some fix in `user` model to save `roles` in to places (if the column exists, then save here, and also save to `roles_table`), 'couse while you run your commands there can be new registrations
3. Run `artisan` command for changing the data (moving the relationship to another table)
4. Run `migration` to drop the old column
5. Remove fix from `user` model (that saves `roles` in two places)

Comment: Thank you. This is how we ended up doing it.